# Select 1 row query insert into multi row

Tags: sql

I have existing data like this:

Table A

```
bill      type            amount
-----------------------------------          
10        Food             100          
11        Beverage          50
12        Food             200
```

Table `Master GL`:

```
Type      D/C     GL_CODE
-------------------------
Food      D       12345
Food      C       56789
Beverage  D       88888
Beverage  C       99999
```

I need to select all row in table A, insert this into below Table B

1 row in Table A will insert into 2 row in table B, also will select the GL code from table Master GL, to get the GL code.

```
D/C     GL CODE          Amount      bill
-----------------------------------------
D       12345            100         10
C       56789            100         10
D       88888             50         11
C       99999             50         11
D       12345            200         12
C       56789            200         12
```

Can anyone advise me the query?

Thank you

Comment: Can you **EXPLAIN** how you get from `Table A` to `Table B` ??  What are you doing? Don't leave us hanging and guessing....... How do you get from `Food` and `Beverage` to these `GL Code` values?!?!?!!?

Comment: sory i forgot to put the master gl table.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should join *TableA*  with *MasterGL* on *Type*
In SQL Server

```
INSERT INTO TableB (DC, GL_CODE, Amount , bill)
SELECT M.DC,
       M.GL_CODE,
       A.Amount ,
       A.bill
FROM   TableA A
       JOIN mastergl M
         ON A.type = M.type
```